# Значення слів розум та розсудок

Tags: значення-слів, вибір-слова, калька

Тлумачний словник подає слова [розсудок](http://sum.in.ua/s/rozsudok) та [розум](http://sum.in.ua/s/ROZUM) як синоніми:

> РОЗСУ́ДОК, дку, чол., рідко. Те саме, що розум 1, 2. Бугров потер рукою остуджене чоло, розсудок повернувся до нього (Іван Микитенко, II, 1957, 281); Тут потрібний холодний розсудок і велика обережність (Дмитро Ткач, Моряки, 1948, 121).

Однак багато [джерел](http://textbooks.net.ua/content/view/5193/45/) з філософії стверджують, що це різні поняття:

> Розсудок — початковий рівень мислення, де оперування абстракціями відбувається в межах певної незмінної, наперед заданої схеми.
>      Це здатність послідовно й коректно будувати свої думки, класифікувати й систематизувати факти. Поняття тут розглядається як стале, незмінне, поза його розвитком та взаємозв´язками. Головною функцією розсудку є розкладання та обчислення. Розсудок є побутовою, повсякденною формою мислення, іншими словами — здоровим глуздом. Логіка розсудку — це формальна логіка, яка більше переймається готовим знанням, ніж становленням його змісту. Вона вивчає структуру висловлювань і доведень.
>    Розум — вищий рівень раціонального пізнання, якому властиві творче оперування абстракціями та рефлексією, спрямованість на усвідомлення власних форм та передумов, самопізнання.

Також у [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA) зазначено:

> Розсу́док або глузд — початковий рівень мислення, де оперування абстракціями відбувається в межах певної незмінної, наперед заданої схеми. Забезпечує оперування поняттями за певним наперед заданим алгоритмом без усвідомлення їхньої природи.
>
> Функція розсудку — класифікувати факти, робити логічні розумові висновки, систематизувати знання за суворими правилами і схемами.
>
> На противагу розсудку розум — вищий рівень раціонального пізнання, якому властиві творче оперування абстракціями та рефлексією, спрямованість на усвідомлення власних форм та передумов, самопізнання.

То ж чи вважати ці слова різними за значенням? Також цікавить саме слово *розсудок*. Чи не є воно калькою з російської(бо дуже схоже з російським "рассудок")? На жаль джерел на підтвердження цієї думки не знайшла.

Answer (score 1):

Почнемо із СУМу, де зазначено, що [розум](http://sum.in.ua/s/rozum) та [розсудок](http://sum.in.ua/s/rozsudok) (вживається рідше) - це одне і теж і мають значення:

> Здатність людини мислити, відображати і пізнавати об'єктивну
>   дійсність.

А також можуть бути синонімами до слова "[мислення](http://sum.in.ua/s/myslennja)". Синонімами є ці слова і згідно до [Словника синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BC).

Однак, коли ми говоримо про філософію, то варто розрізняти поняття "розум" та "розсудок":

> РОЗСУДОК і РОЗУМ - поняття, вироблені в історії філософії для
>   позначення якісних особливостей мислення на певних ступенях буття або
>   логічного розвитку. В античній філософії вони розглядались як
>   властивості, неоднаково притаманні різним істотам. Типовою є думка
>   Піфагора: душа людини поділяється на три частини: ум (розум), розсудок
>   і пристрасть. **Розум** і пристрасть є і в живих істотах, а **розсудок** -
>   лише в людині... ([Філософський енцеклопедичний словник](https://filos_uk.academic.ru/2615/%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D1%96_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BC))

Згідно до Вікіпедії ([джерело1](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BC_(%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D1%96%D1%8F)), [джерело2](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA)), ці поняття також різні (стосується також філософії):

> На противагу розсудку розум — вищий рівень раціонального пізнання,
>   якому властиві творче оперування абстракціями та рефлексією,
>   спрямованість на усвідомлення власних форм та передумов, самопізнання.
>
> Протиставляється розуму — вищій формі теоретичного осмислення
>   дійсності. (про розсудок)

Comment: Не зовсім зрозумів, чому Ви вважаєте слово «мислення» синонімом до них (хіба що дуже частковим, на мою думку).

Comment: В СУМі є інформація, що розум - це те саме, що мислення

Comment: Так, але лише в одному зі значень. Причому це навіть не друге значення повністю, а радше «2а» (а ще є 2б, 2в тощо). Як на мене, це дуже частковий синонім (не повний).

Answer (score 0):

Згідно з [словником синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA)

> ***РО́ЗУМ*** (здатність окремої людини запам’ятовувати, оцінювати
>   обстановку, події тощо та відповідно діяти і поводитися; звичайний,
>   природний стан людської свідомості), **УМ, ЗДОРО́ВИЙ ГЛУЗД, ГЛУЗД,
>   ТОЛК***розм.* [**ТОВК** *діал.*],
>   **МО́ЗОК** *розм.*, **ГОЛОВА́** *розм.*, **КЕБЕ́ТА** *розм.*, **РОЗСУ́ДОК** *розм.*, **РО́ЗСУД** *рідше*, **РОЗУМІ́ННЯ** *рідше*, **ТЯ́МА** *розм.*, **ТЯ́МКА** *розм*., **ЗАСТАНО́ВА** *діал.*

Великий тлумачний словник сучасної укрваїнської мови

> ***[Розум](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53408/978275.html)*** 
>   -у, ч. 1. здатність людини мислити, відображати і пізнавати об'єктивну дійсність. 
>   2. Те саме, що  мислення
>
> ***[Розсудок](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53408/977894.html)*** -дку, ч. , рідко.Те саме, що розум 1), 2).

***Розум*** і ***Розсудок*** (розмовне) є синонімами, отже можуть вживатися як взаємозамінні.

Джерел для підтвердження чи спростування того, що слово ***розсудок*** є калькою з російської не знайшла.